# Oracle Entity Frameework Autoincrement?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I'm thinking of using ODP.NET Entity framework in my application, and i was wondering how the autoincrement is handled. When working with ODP.NET without EF i was using a sequence and sequence.next in my inserts.
But how should i handle this with EF ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used sequences and triggers - it was the only solution that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you retrieve the sequence's NEXT_VAL in the BEFORE INSERT trigger of the table (see [sample](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/AutoNumber.php)).

In EF, set StoreGeneratedPattern of the PK column to Identity ([MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/a0901f4a-df35-4690-8323-2df522c24539/)).

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I've allready tried it, if i set it to identity i get "null" in the ID column, when inserting.

Comment: @maesphisto Check if you configure the key column: ```modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(t => t.ID);

Answer (score 0):

In EntityFramework 6 you can configure your model to DatabaseGeneratedOption to Identity and set the key column:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //Configure default schema
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("Admin");

        //Map pk in table
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasKey(t => t.ID_CERT);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(t => t.ID_CERT)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
```

After that update your database:

```
update-database
```

This you create the sequences and triggers automatically for you.

If you need some custom trigger see [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity) some samples, and create an empty migration with the trigger:

```
public partial class SomeMigration : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql("create or replace trigger TR_CUSTOM ... ");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```